# TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes) creates infinite look if OnRedirectToIdentityProvider is set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor

I been scratching my head for days for this:

Our app runs on Kubernetes with nginx reverse proxy as usual with OpenIdConnect. It is a Blazor Server app that logs in users and then request access tokens to call other apis like MS Graph:

If I do not set the context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri it will get redirected to http://localhost/signin-oidc <= app is running in the container on port 80 and it is mapped to port 8080 which is the one nginx redirects. So with the code below it works nicely after the user is authenticated with AAD and lands on the home page as long as I do not request an access token later.

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Host"))
                        {
                           ** context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://" + context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"] + this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetValue<string>("CallbackPath")**;
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
```

But this is the problem, if I try then to get an access token (for any api, not just graph), it will go into an infinite loop.

This will trigger an inifite loop

```
     services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi("user.read")
                   .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

This too

```
@code {

    protected string? accessToken;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            accessToken = await TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string baseUri = ConsentHandler.BaseUri.ToString();
            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I can repro on the dev box, even if forwarding is not needed. As soon as the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider is set, none of the token acquisition functions works well.

So to run on Kubernetes I cannot request access tokens, as long as I keep the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider to land on the right page

On dev box I need to disable the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider for tokens to work.

So it is a mutually exclusive situation.

Is there a workaround for this?

Is there a way to force AAD to go to the actual user facing endpoint without the need of including the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider code?

Thanks

Explained already on the description